# Looking for an URL from Multiple Pages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, url-routing

I have written a code only to find out one hotel URL but the code only works in 1st page of list.If the hotel name is in 2nd page list or any other pages this code is unable to find out. I am Unable to search URL from Multiple Pages using Python This is not working to search from multiple pages.My code is given below:

```
def parse(locality,checkin_date,checkout_date,sort,hotl_nam):
    checkIn = checkin_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    checkOut = checkout_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
     # TA rendering the autocomplete list using this API   
    geo_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/TypeAheadJson?action=API&startTime='+str(int(time()))+'&uiOrigin=GEOSCOPE&source=GEOSCOPE&interleaved=true&types=geo,theme_park&neighborhood_geos=true&link_type=hotel&details=true&max=12&injectNeighborhoods=true&query='+locality
    api_response  = requests.get(geo_url, verify=False).json()
    #getting the TA url for th equery from the autocomplete response
    url_from_autocomplete = "http://www.tripadvisor.com"+api_response['results'][0]['url']
    print ('URL found %s'%url_from_autocomplete)
    geo = api_response['results'][0]['value']   
    #Formating date for writing to file 
    date = checkin_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")+"_"+checkout_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
    #form data to get the hotels list from TA for the selected date
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the Max parameter. `max=100`

```
geo_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/TypeAheadJson?action=API&startTime='+str(int(time()))+'&uiOrigin=GEOSCOPE&source=GEOSCOPE&interleaved=true&types=geo,theme_park&neighborhood_geos=true&link_type=hotel&details=true&max=100&injectNeighborhoods=true&query='+locality
```

Comment: Looks like it is the max number of results returned.